# Nginx http to https redirect not working when listening to upstream loadbalancer

Tags: nginx, redirect, haproxy

I currently have an HAProxy load balancer out front, without SSL termination, that routes traffic to a couple web servers. On the webserver, nginx terminates the SSL, and in theory provides http to https redirection. However when requesting http in the browser, it does not redirect, but instead throws a '400 Bad Request' error saying the plain http request was sent to an https port. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Example nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen private.ip:80;
    allow lb.ip;
    allow secondary_lb.ip;
    deny all;

    server_name qa.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen private.ip:443 ssl;
    allow lb.ip;
    allow secondary_lb.ip;
    deny all;

    server_name qa.example.com;

    # rest of config
}
```

I believe the relevant sections of the HAProxy configuration are this (some ansible variables present, but you get the idea)...

```
frontend http
    bind    my_ip:80
    bind    my_ip:443
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    default_backend app_pool

backend app_pool
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    {% for server in backend_webservers %}
    server {{ server.name }} {{ server.ip }}:443 check
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is you HAProxy configuration ?

Comment: Added a snippet of my haproxy config, do you think I should redirect at the haproxy layer instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your configuration, HAProxy is routing the request to 443 port even if it is a HTTP traffic received on port 80.
The best way to deal with this is to configure the http to https redirection on HAProxy and not on the backend. So you will have to add the following to HAProxy frontend:

> redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to mark this as accepted, because I think this redirection is where this should actually live (instead of with nginx in each individual web server). However for my own curiosity, shouldn't the very first server block in the nginx configuration do the same exact redirection? If port 80 received, redirect with 301 to 443? I think I'm missing something key here

Comment: Yes the first server block in the nginx does the redirection but the problem is that there will never be traffic reaching port 80 of nginx becuase HAProxy is always sending traffic to port 443, look to your server line in HAProxy "server {{ server.name }} {{ server.ip }}:443 check"